# Are these two implementations of typedef with a structure equivalent?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

What, if any, are the differences between these two implementations of typedef with a structure?

```
typedef struct Data{
    int x;
    int y;
} Data;
```

and

```
struct Data{
    int x;
    int y;
};
typedef struct Data Data;
```

Comment: You don't need to use either of them in C++, so I'm removing the C++ tag.

Comment: C != C++. Please only a question once you know what language you want to ask about.

Comment: c or c++ ? I does make a difference because in c++ you would not write `typedef struct Data {...` unless you try hard to make your code look like c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371169/why-using-a-typedef-after-struct-definition

Comment: My mistake. No excuse for including C++ in there. My question is about C. Thanks for removing the tag @NeilButterworth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they both typedef `Data` to `struct Data`, allthough often people would use different names to avoid confusion.

Note that in C++, you dont need the `struct` part at all when using the type, so its common to not have the `typedef` at all. The same applies to `enum`, etc.

```
struct Data
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
void foo1(Data data); // OK in C++
void foo2(struct Data data); // OK in C or C++, but almost never seen in C++


typedef struct Data2_
{
    int x;
    int y;
}Data2;
void foo3(Data2 data); // OK in C or C++, but C++ code tends to skip the typedef as well
```

Comment: Note that without the `typedef`, the C++ code would use `Data2_t` while C would use `struct Data2_t` (rather than `Data2` — I'd make it `struct Data2 { … }`).  Also note that POSIX makes a grab for the `_t` suffix — you run the risk of conflicting with POSIX headers when you use it.  (And yes, I've seen it happen, and yes, it causes headaches.)

Comment: Its still valid for the C++ to use the typedefed one, the other one is often not even a really a "published" name in most C libraries. and yes about the `_t`. between Win32 and POSIX everything is a pain...

Comment: Many C libraries — look at POSIX, for example, and also the Linux kernel (which isn't a library, but…) — only use `struct DoHickey` and not a `typedef struct DoHickey DoHickey;` in sight.  At least when the type is not intended to be opaque.  (So `DIR` is an opaque type, but `struct dirent` is one you poke around inside.)

Comment: Note, the only minor criticism here is the use of `_t` — and that's a rule that's often breached.  The rest is just minor clarification.  Sorry about the amount of noise.

Comment: Actually i think its all over :) I happened to have zlib headers open for somthing and they are using `_s` and typedefs (and also some nice `alloc_func`, `internal_state`, etc. things to trip users over...) and libssh2 is using `_LIBSSH2` prefix so another broken rule :(. Mostly my point was in C++ because `struct`  isnt needed to use it, that developers tend to just not bother since the question was tagged at the time.